# Closed subsets of empty interior are of 1st category

Tags: metric-spaces, baire-category

In a metric space is it true that closed sets with empty interior are of 1st category? I.e., that it can be represented as a at most countable union of meager sets? Thanks

Comment: A closed set with empty interior **is** meagre.

Comment: If a closed set has an empty interior, then the closed set is nowhere dense. I don't understand the question.

Comment: Indeed it is, i font know what i was thinking, thanks :D